# triple lost embedding generator setup error

Tags: python, deep-learning, neural-network, face-recognition

my code:

```
base_cnn = resnet.ResNet50(
    weights="imagenet", input_shape=target_shape + (3,), include_top=False
)

flatten = layers.Flatten()(base_cnn.output)
dense1 = layers.Dense(512, activation="relu")(flatten)
dense1 = layers.BatchNormalization()(dense1)
dense2 = layers.Dense(256, activation="relu")(dense1)
dense2 = layers.BatchNormalization()(dense2)
output = layers.Dense(256)(dense2)

embedding = Model(base_cnn.input, output, name="Embedding")

trainable = False
for layer in base_cnn.layers:
    if layer.name == "conv5_block1_out":
        trainable = True
    layer.trainable = trainable
```

---

`error: ValueError: The input must have 3 channels; Received` input_shape=(200, 200, 3)``

---

it raises this error when i looked into the tf code it doens't want both the input_shape[0] = 3 and weights = imagenet i don't see why it won't allow it.

i tried to put the three in shape[0] but when doing the transfer learning i get an error becuase the original network is (200,200,3)